# How to set the background color of the ToolBar on the OS X?

Tags: macos, colors, background, toolbar

I don't know how to set the background color of the toolbar on the OS X，there are some difference between this and iOS development.Maybe I can customize a view, put some buttons?

Comment: I have looked at NSToolbar all API,but can't find the setting the background color